# Try different odbc connect calls

Tags: php, odbc

I would like to try to connect to a database (using odbc) where I necessarily don't know the exact password. That is, I have a couple of different alternatives what the password might be, and I want my code to figure out which one is right.

How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: Just wrap the call to `odbc_connect` in a foreach loop trying all the passwords.

Comment: How do I know if a call was successful?

Comment: please refer to the Return Values in the PHP docs. `odbc_connect` will return either a resource or 0 (false)

Comment: Thanks, but this really just opens up a can of worms for me. I would really need a minimal example since it's not obvious for me how to deal with a binary outcome space of 0 and a resource (would, for example, be easier if it was simply true or false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the call to `odbc_connect` in a foreach loop trying all the passwords:

```
function my_odbc_connect($dsn, $user, array $passwords) {
    foreach ($passwords as $password) {
        $connection = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);
        if (is_resource($connection)) {
            return $connection;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then just do

```
$connection = my_odbc_connect('blah', 'user', array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer probably solves my problem as stated. However, once I use this type of function, the whole thing goes apeshit, throwing out output about the fact that it cannot connect to the database. This becomes a problem since I, in the end, send everything that I echo in the PHP code to a Javascript variable. That is, if I'm trying to send back a string saying "success" to the Javascript, it gets clogged up by a lot of other output.

Anybody have an idea where I could go to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Speldosa see http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors. You dont want errors to be displayed in production. Also consider http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php or, if you are lazy, just suppress the error reporting with an `@`.