# Suppress PHP error from a odbc_connect call

Tags: php, odbc

Let's say I do a odbc_connect call, deliberately using erroneous information, as follows:

```
<?PHP odbc_connect('bogus','bogus','bogus'); ?>
```

Now, [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) states that odbc_connect "[r]eturns an ODBC connection id or 0 (FALSE) on error". I'm okay with the 0 being returned, but when I'm running the file (using [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)), I also receive error messages telling me that something went wrong.

I would like to suppress this error message, since I'm [trying to build a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061825/try-different-odbc-connect-calls) that only echoes a certain piece of text, like "unsuccessful", when the information for the database call was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the error-suppression operator `@`.

```
<?php
    $conn = @odbc_connect('bogus','bogus','bogus');
?>
```

Comment: Isn't it better to properly handle the exception, rather than "ignore" it?

Comment: @Matt: `deliberately using erroneous information`.  If you know it's throwing an error, and are purposely throwing one, who cares? :-P

Comment: I think OP is deliberately using erroneous information so that he can "see" the error and write code to handle it. Once this is done, it seems to me that OP will use valid information so that he has all his bases covered.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, the problem I have only comes up when I'm putting in erroneous information, so it's about writing something that can handle that scenario as well as the case when the information actually is right.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `try-catch`:

```
<?php
try {
    odbc_connect('bogus', 'bogus', 'bogus');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle your exception
}
```

Comment: Best way to handle the situation - catch the error, (possibly) do something with it and let your script carry on.

Comment: What would you suggest me doing with the error? This will basically be the basic for a script stepping through a lot of different login alternatives, and most of them will be wrong. I'm still using if-statements to determine whether the call was successful or not.

Comment: @Speldosa There are a bunch of things you can do - write an error to the log and redirect the user to an error screen would probably be the best thing. Something like "OOPS! You broke our site! WTF?!"

Comment: @Matt: Haha ;) Well, the thing here is that it isn't really an error. I know that the user (user in this case means the client who is going to install the php framework on his/hers machine) have a database called either x,y, and z and I'm just trying to figure out which one it is. So it's expected that there will be a couple of "errors" while looking for the right one. I really don't know why I would want to handle them in some special way (I don't throw an exception every time an if-statement fails). I'm going to go with the @-solution for now I think.

Comment: I've runned into another situation in which this would be the preffered sollution. However, I can't catch the error. A big generic error box is displayed and whatever I place in the catch block is never runned.

Comment: Sorry, docs say that on error function simply return `FALSE` so this answer is of dubious value.

Comment: In that case, OP can set the result of odbc_connect to a variable, then test that variable to see if it's `false`, and handle that situation. `$test = odbc_connect('', '', ''); if ($test === false) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `@` to suppress error messages on a single line - but it isn't good practice.

```
<?PHP @odbc_connect('bogus','bogus','bogus'); ?>
```

Error messages are there for a reason, don't ignore them. Use something like @Matt suggests and trap them as needed - not just hush them up.