# Unexpected behavior using try-catch statement when using odbc_exec in PHP

Tags: php, odbc, try-catch, wampserver

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074937/suppress-php-error-from-a-odbc-connect-call), I got the advice to use a try-catch statement on an odbc_connect call. Well, said and done, that's what I've tried to do.

The following code, which tries to connect to a database using bogus login information, does not work as excpected.

```
<?php
  try
  {
    odbc_connect('BogusDatabase','BogusUser','BogusPassword');
  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
  }
?>
```

I would expect the output to be a string saying "Something went wrong!". Instead I get this:

[image: Damn! I don't want this!]

I'm using [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to run my PHP code. I don't know if this is a part of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Aurimas said, you have to use error_handler to do that.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

this function look after the errors that occured in your script and call a function that you provide each time an error is throwed.

A simple handler is

```
function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

It throws a ErrorException each time an error is raised in your script.
so this whole script will behave as you expect :

```
 set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
 });
 try
{
  odbc_connect('BogusDatabase','BogusUser','BogusPassword');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo "Something went wrong!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On PHP manual [Exeptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> Internal PHP functions mainly use Error reporting, only modern Object oriented extensions use exceptions. However, errors can be simply translated to exceptions with ErrorException

Take a look at the [ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) and set your custom error handle, to catch these errors.

Comment: Do you have a non-greek (or non-geek) version of this? :) I've been using PHP for a while now, but I can't understand anything about what is said here.

Comment: Look at the @artragis answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function is not throwing an Exception. Instead, it's triggering a warning. If you don't want warnings to display, you can use the error_reporting() to display only actual errors.

Comment: Well, no, I don't want the warning to display. However, I also want to know when something went wrong with connecting to the database so that I could try to fix it, hence, I would like to get to the code in the catch block. I'm lookin at Aurimas link above, but it's like greek to me and I don't really understand how I should implement it.

Comment: Well, odbc_connect returns false on error, so you could do something like this:

    if(!odbc_connect(...))
        // error, try to handle it
    else
        // ok