# PHP writing to odbc datasource fails

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

today I need some help with a php-script, that doesn't work anymore.

I have to setup a backup server, where a simple timesheet works with a web-interface, connected to an odbc datasource (Access 2007-database)
Everything works well on the original server but now the hardware is about to be changed.
On both servers, the PHP Version 5.4.9 is running, for compatibility-reason. (local network, so no risk with the old php-version)

Reading from the datasource works well but I could not write to the datasource. Is there any readonly-flag, that I didn't find, in the datasource-environment?
I have no idea how to get over this problem.
I could follow the code up to the "INSERT INTO" command without any fault.

```
$result = odbc_exec($con,"INSERT INTO Zeitkarten (BeginnTätigkeit,EndeTätigkeit,Mitarbeiter,Projekt,ArbeitscodeNr,datum,Pause,AnzahlUeber,FZhin,FZrueck,Anmerkung) 
          VALUES (#".$_POST['kommen']."#,#".$_POST['gehen']."#,$benutzer,".$_POST['projekt'].",".$_POST['adt'].",#".$_POST['heute']."#,".str_Replace(",",".",$_POST['pause']).",".str_Replace(",",".",$_POST['ama']).",".str_Replace(",",".",$_POST['fzhin']).",".str_Replace(",",".",$_POST['fzrueck']).",'".$_POST['anmerkung']."')");
                    echo $result;
                    }
```

This should normally echo any result (e.g. on the original server I get: Resource id #136). Here I get nothing.

Can please anyone help me to search the problem?

Comment: Try checking for [odbc_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-error.php) messages

Comment: Hi aynber, many thanks for the hint. I get that Message: "Operation must use an updateable query" error S1000. Now I'm not really smarter. I tried to insert a new recordset, which worked hundrets of times on the old server. Any ideas?

Comment: `echo` is always dangerous when debugging. If you used `var_dump` instead, I'm assuming you'd find that it is returning `false` per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php).

Comment: Changing the hardware often implies changing of other things. Is it possible you also have a newer version of ODBC because the OS is newer?

Comment: Chris Haas, you are right, I got a newer version of odbc-driver. That is the only difference between the servers I found yet. So I'll try to find out what's the difference.

Comment: My other guess is that it is a permissions issue that is getting interpreted as effectively a read/write problem. I'd make sure that the PHP process (or IIS, depending on how it is configured) has permission to both the file and folder. I think the latter is needed for a lock.

Comment: Oh no... that was simple and it's distressing... Thank you so much, the folder was only readable for users.

Comment: @Telefisch, could you post what you did to resolve this as an answer an accept it?

Comment: hmm... I could not mark my own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your issue involves read-only permissions on the data source file, consider two best practices going forward:

- Parameterization to facilitate code security especially with `$POST` variables as well as readability and maintainability without need of messy variable concatenation or quote punctuation.
  Parameters are supported in the `odbc` library using [`odbc_prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php).
- Error handling using `try/catch` for more informative errors or exceptions per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438549/1422451).

Below uses MS Access's `CDate()` and avoid need of enclosing `#` and converts numeric types of parameters with PHP's `floatval`. Adjust untested code as needed.

```php
// ENSURE ERRORS RAISE AS EXCEPTIONS
set_error_handler(
    function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) { 
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    }
);

// PREPARED STATEMENT WITH ? PLACEHOLDERS
$sql = "INSERT INTO Zeitkarten
          (BeginnTätigkeit, EndeTätigkeit, Mitarbeiter, Projekt, ArbeitscodeNr,
           datum, [Pause], AnzahlUeber, FZhin, FZrueck, Anmerkung) 
        VALUES (CDate(?), CDate(?), ?, ?, ?, CDate(?), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try { 
    // BIND PARAMS AND EXECUTE
    $stmt = odbc_prepare($con, $sql);
    $result = odbc_execute(
         $stmt, 
         array( 
             $_POST['kommen'],
             $_POST['gehen'], 
             $benutzer, 
             $_POST['projekt'], 
             $_POST['adt'], 
             $_POST['heute'],
             floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['pause'])),
             floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['ama'])),
             floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['fzhin'])),
             floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['fzrueck'])),
             $_POST['anmerkung']
         )
    ); 

    echo $result; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    // ECHO EXCEPTION MESSAGE
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was simple...
The folder, the database is stored in, was only readable for standard users.
Now the users have wright-rights to that folder and the odbc-connection could write to the database.

Thanks to Chris Haas